# Real Time Fetching data with laravel5.2 , vue.js and pusher

Tags: laravel, notifications, real-time, vue.js, pusher

I have a problem. 
 I'm using pusher for real time notification and when It runs it notifies me using noty, 
but I also want it to show the number of the new notification in real time in my view similar to facebook.

```
<span class="label label-warning" v-show="new_count">@{{ new_count }}<!-- get the new notifications --></span>
```

How do I do this?

this are my codes.

> nav.js

```
new Vue({
    el: '#nav',
    data: {
        new_count: 0
    },

    methods: {
        getNewCount: function () {
            this.$http.get('cron', function(new_count){
                console.log(new_count);
                this.new_count = new_count;
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }
});
```

> Cron Job Controller. this method runs every minute.

```
class CronJobController extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $old_fail_notification = FailNotification::where('seen', 0)->count();
        $subjects_with_fail = Grade::where('grade', 'F')->groupBy('subject_id')->orderBy('subject_id', 'ASC')->get();
        return response()->json(['new_count' => 2]); //send this to navbar
        foreach ($subjects_with_fail as $subject) {
            $subject_to_check = Grade::where('grade', 'F')->where('subject_id', $subject->subject_id)->where('reviewed', '0')->get(); //add if grade is IC or D

            if (count($subject_to_check) >= 3) {
                $failed = new FailNotification();
                $failed->message = '[subject-'.$subject->subject_id.'] can now be opened.';
                $failed->save();

                foreach ($subject_to_check as $subject) {
                    $subject = Grade::find($subject->id);
                    $subject->reviewed = 1;
                    $subject->save();
                }
            }
        }
        $fail_notification = FailNotification::all()->count();
        //UPDATE NOTIFICATION COUNT HERE REAL TIME USING AJAX
        if ($fail_notification > $old_fail_notification) {
            $new_notification_count = $fail_notification - $old_fail_notification;

            Pusher::trigger('test-channel', 'test-event', [
                'name' => 'You have a new',
                'message' => 'Notification'
                ]);

            Pusher::trigger('navbar-channel', 'navbar-event', [
                'new_notif_count' => $new_notification_count,
                ]);

            return response()->json(['new_count' => $new_notification_count]); //send this to navbar
        }


    }
}
```

please tell what I'm doing wrong and how do I do it right.

Comment: And where are you subscribing to the pusher service? as said below, the get method from vue.resource, is a single method, and you need to constantly listen to pusher events. In the docs they say that you do that with a susbcirbe method? where is that in your Vue code?

Comment: thanks! I'm now studying subscribing in pusher service.

Answer (score -1):

`this.$http.get()` does a single GET request to the server which doesnt keep the connection to the server open. If you want to add realtime features to your website you should implement something like socket.io which implements WebSockets. You can also do `longpolling` on the backend or `shortpolling` on the client for near-realtime features.

Comment: is socket.io different that pusher?
should I use them both or socket.io only?

Comment: You wouldn't need socket.io anymore since you want to use Pusher. But technically you can use both, they are both web socket technologies. Socket.io is an open source libray to implement web sockets yourself whereas Pusher is a company providing that service for you via their servers.

Answer (score -1):

If your php code is right, then you should add the subscriber in Vue code.

first include pusher script (it seems that isn't availaible as an npm package)

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
```

then, in vue, instantiate your pusher instance using your `API_KEY`, and suscribe and listen

```
ready () {
  const pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY')

  // susbcribe to your channel
  const channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel')

  // listen to the event defined on that channel
  channel.bind('test-event', data => {
    console.log(data.message)
  })
}
```

That should work. Now about your php code. I'm not sure that the `trigger`event is a class method of pusher, in the docs I saw that trigger is used as an instance method, and make sense since you need to pass your api key and others authentication values, and that is done when you create your instance.

```
require('Pusher.php');

$pusher = new Pusher("APP_KEY", "APP_SECRET", "APP_ID");
$pusher->trigger('test_channel', 'test-event', array('message' => 'hello world') );
```

So, check if you are correct in your server code, but you are definitly doing it wrong on the client, try those changes and check if is waht you needed